# Method making the output display 0 for java

Tags: java

I don't why I cannot make it display 0,1,2,3,4,5 it keeps on displaying 1,2,3,4,5 instead when I enter 5 as my integer. Without using the method you would just switch the greater or less than or equal to, to make it display 0,1,2,3,4,5. But for the method I do not know why it doesn't changes when I try putting equal to.

```
public static void printSequence(int num, int num1){
    int range = 0;

    if (num > num1){
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++){
            range += 1;
            System.out.println(range);
        }
    }   
    else if (num < num1){
        for (int j = 0; j > num; j--){
        range -= 1;
        System.out.println(range);
        }
    }
}
```

Enter an integer : 5
1
2
3
4
5

Comment: Well... what is `range` set to before you first increase it by one and then print it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First print the range:

```
System.out.println(range);
```

Then increment it:

```
range += 1;
```

You are incrementing it first and that's the problem. I hope it helps. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: By clicking the check? I am still new to this site sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use something like this:

```
  else if (num < num1){
        for (int j = num1; j > 0; j--){
        range = j;
        System.out.println(range);
        }
```

With start from `j = num1` and assign `j` to `range`.